We're sorry, but we're not sure what the error is
I am new to linux and I am trying to install ubuntu 24. However I cannot get it to install. I get the message "We're sorry, but we're not sure what the error is".
I tried running it a few times, and switching usb stick to another one, but it did not work.
I am trying to install ubuntu alongside windows on dell xps 13 7390 2-in-1
Intel core i7-1065G7x8
intel iris plus graphics icl gt2
16Gb ram & 512 gb ssd
This is an extract of the log:
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Err:22 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware amd64 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Fetched 135 MB in 10min 7s (223 kB/s)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         E: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb  Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         E: Some files failed to download
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         TIMED subp(['udevadm', 'settle']): 0.006
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys/firmware/efi/efivars'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/sys/firmware/efi/efivars'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['mount', '--make-private', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks/installing-kernel: FAIL: installing kernel
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/builtin/cmd-curthooks: FAIL: curtin command curthooks
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             ret = args.func(args)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2234, in curthooks
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             builtin_curthooks(cfg, target, state)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 2058, in builtin_curthooks
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             install_kernel(cfg, target)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 403, in install_kernel
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             install(kernel_cfg.package)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/curthooks.py", line 369, in install
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             distro.install_packages([pkg], target=target, env=env)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 474, in install_packages
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             return install_cmd('install', args=pkglist, opts=opts, target=target,
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 256, in run_apt_command
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             cmd_rv = apt_install(mode, args, opts=opts, env=env, target=target,
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/distro.py", line 304, in apt_install
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             cmd_rv = inchroot.subp(cmd + dl_opts + packages, env=env,
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 843, in subp
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             return subp(*args, **kwargs)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 323, in subp
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 172, in _subp
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:             raise ProcessExecutionError(stdout=out, stderr=err,
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', '--download-only', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Exit code: 100
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Reason: -
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Stdout: ''
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Stderr: ''
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Unexpected error while running command.
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Command: ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/target/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/target', 'apt-get', '--quiet', '--assume-yes', '--option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io', '--option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold', 'install', '--download-only', 'linux-generic-hwe-24.04']
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Exit code: 100
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Reason: -
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Stdout: ''
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         Stderr: ''
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]:         
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_log.3784[10671]: Stderr: ''
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_event.3784[3784]:  executing curtin install curthooks step
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_event.3784[3784]: installing system
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_event.3784[3784]: 
Nov 03 01:17:11 ubuntu subiquity_event.3784[3784]:   curtin command install

What should I do?

Did you try verifying the image you downloaded on usb stick if it not corrupted? If you copied same corrupted image on both usb sticks then it won't help. Your log file did suggest issues in downloading firmware

I did not verify(done know how ;). But I did download a new image for the second try. I have used balenaEtcher both times

Are you able to boot from the Ubuntu USB drive?

Yes, I boots fine. It displays the error after setting everything up, settings, partitioning etc. after like 5 minutes of trying to install ubuntu on the computer

Looking at the linked error messages, the problem is somewhat obvious but the cause is not.
Excerpting from the log, the following is relevant:
Err:22 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntunoble-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware amd64 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4
Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer)

From this, it appears that the USB has booted and the install is well enough advanced that this is probably not a problem with the USB, but a problem with the network.
The installer is trying to download operating system components from the network and getting disconnected.  Either the server it has selected is overloaded or otherwise failing, or some upstream network component (router? proxy server?) is disconnecting the download attempt.

Thanks so much for replying! I have tried with mobile hotspot but no luck either

You might be able to debug this by trying to browse to the URL in the error message with a web browser.

Thanks so much for your help. I managed to install ubuntu by just not connecting to network during installation

I got exactly the same issue and confirmed that connecting to the Internet solved this issue, just like what the OP replied in another reply.
